# Stepping through date in Python

Tags: python, loops, datetime, python-dateutil

Let's say I have a starting date of `datetime(2007, 2, 15)`.

I want to step this date in a loop so that it's advanced to the 1st and 15th of each month.

So `datetime(2007, 2, 15)` would step to `datetime(2007, 3, 1)`.

In the next iteration, it would step to `datetime(2007, 3, 15)`... then to `datetime(2007, 4, 1)` and so forth.

Is there any possible way to do this with `timedelta` or `dateutils` considering that, the number of days it has to step by, continuously changes?

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
for m in range(1, 13):
    for d in (1, 15):
        print str(datetime(2013, m, d))

2013-01-01 00:00:00
2013-01-15 00:00:00
2013-02-01 00:00:00
2013-02-15 00:00:00
2013-03-01 00:00:00
2013-03-15 00:00:00
2013-04-01 00:00:00
2013-04-15 00:00:00
2013-05-01 00:00:00
2013-05-15 00:00:00
2013-06-01 00:00:00
2013-06-15 00:00:00
2013-07-01 00:00:00
2013-07-15 00:00:00
2013-08-01 00:00:00
2013-08-15 00:00:00
2013-09-01 00:00:00
2013-09-15 00:00:00
2013-10-01 00:00:00
2013-10-15 00:00:00
2013-11-01 00:00:00
2013-11-15 00:00:00
2013-12-01 00:00:00
2013-12-15 00:00:00
```

I tend to work with datetime more than date objects, but you could use datetime.date depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate through each day and ignore any date where the day of month isn't 1 or 15.  Example:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime(2007,2,15)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2008,4,1)

while current_time <= end_time:
  if current_time.day in [1,15]:
    print(current_time)
  current_time += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

This way you can iterate across multiple years and start on the 15th, both of which would be problematic with doog's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime    
d = datetime(month=2,year=2007,day=15)    
current_day = next_day = d.day
current_month = next_month = d.month
current_year = next_year = d.year   
for i in range(25):
    if current_day == 1:
        next_day = 15
    elif current_day == 15:
        next_day = 1
        if current_month == 12:
            next_month = 1
            next_year+=1
        else:
            next_month+=1    
    new_date=datetime(month=next_month,year=next_year,day=next_day)
    print new_date
    current_day,current_month,current_year=next_day,next_month,next_year

2007-03-01 00:00:00
2007-03-15 00:00:00
2007-04-01 00:00:00
2007-04-15 00:00:00
2007-05-01 00:00:00
2007-05-15 00:00:00
2007-06-01 00:00:00
2007-06-15 00:00:00
2007-07-01 00:00:00
2007-07-15 00:00:00
2007-08-01 00:00:00
2007-08-15 00:00:00
2007-09-01 00:00:00
2007-09-15 00:00:00
2007-10-01 00:00:00
2007-10-15 00:00:00
2007-11-01 00:00:00
2007-11-15 00:00:00
2007-12-01 00:00:00
2007-12-15 00:00:00
2008-01-01 00:00:00
2008-01-15 00:00:00
2008-02-01 00:00:00
2008-02-15 00:00:00
2008-03-01 00:00:00
```